# Is there a way to populate a select field in django from remote json API and validate it?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, django

I have a model based on geographical data. I'm using an API provided by the French Government using zipcodes to retrieve related city names. For avoiding mispellings or typos, I'm planning to use a select box (which acts as an input field server-side) populated with the results of this API depending on the zipcode provided by the user.

Client-side, its working. I'm able to make jQuery populate the select options correctly. Anyway, server-side, the validation is not working.

I was able to make it work using a custom class, but this is always returning `True`.

```
class DynamicChoiceField(forms.ChoiceField):
  def valid_value(self, value):
    return True
```

How can Django handle that type of field which is (for me) quite common ?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: What are you trying to validate?

Comment: The whole form. Django is expecting a known value from this field and, obviously, it's not. I'm able to pass through using the tips I mentionned, but this is not a solution. I'd like to validate properly this field i.e "the field is empty", "the value is longer than expected" ... To sum up : I'd like to customize Django select field validation on submit.